# Can I convert an annotation into a stroke object?

Tags: grease-pencil, annotation

I started drawing some sketches using the annotation tool, but now would like to convert them to grease pencil Stroke objects.  Is there a way to do this?  Another post mentioned pressing F3 and then running a convert tool on it, but I can't figure out how to even select my annotation object since it doesn't appear in the outliner.

Comment: In Blender 2.8.3 it works indeed that way. Press F3 (shortcut for 'Edit -> Operator Search...' in main menu), then type 'Convert to Grease Pencil' in the search box. In Blender 2.9.0, F3 now is called 'Menu Search...' and there is no more this 'Convert to Grease Pencil' command

Comment: Okay, but convert what to Grease Pencil?  The command that comes up in the search box is for converting Curves or Meshes to Grease Pencil, not Annotations.  I can't even find a way to edit the points of an Annotation or a way to select it so that I could submit it to such an operator.